# What is a good SMTP server for testing email system on Windows

Tags: windows, smtp

I need a simple "fake" SMTP server or decent real SMTP server than can be configured to just dump all the mail it receives.

I've tried Dumpster and it does nothing but error out on me. (I'm not much of a Java guy)  All I really need is a simple program sitting on Port 25 pretending to be an SMTP server.

Suggestions?

I'm on Windows Vista... the standard Windows SMTP server does not seem to be an option.

Comment: See the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241269/method-for-email-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I briefly tried [Neptune](http://donovanbrown.com/post/2008/10/20/Neptune.aspx) for some testing and it worked ok.